# String must contain X amount of numbers (but not necessarily joined)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to validate phone numbers posted on a contact form

I don't want to be too strict and perhaps block any users from submitting the form with a perfectly OK phone number

Instead, the phone no. should just **contain** at least (let's say) 6 number digits **in total**

The string can be anything in any order.. "(44) 123hello88you987howareyou565"

Right now I have this

```
if (!preg_match('/(\d{6,})/', $phone)) { // throw error }
```

But it only considers joined numbers

Comment: Then allow other chars in between: `/(\D*\d){6,}/`!

Comment: That seems to work fine, thank you. Why not answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow other characters in between the digits:

```
!preg_match('/(?:\D*\d){6,}/', $phone)
```

Comment: What does the added ?: do?

Comment: Ok. This I don't understand.. why does it have to be "non-capturing"?

Comment: Just because there's no need to be capturing. It doesn't really matter actually.

Comment: +1 for short and sweet!... optionally you could kill the comma and go with `{6}` as that satisfies the condition... Also add a start `^` to speed up failure?... just ideas, not criticisms. @mowgli, most regex heads like to optimize expressions so they do only what is necessary. Regular `(parentheses)` would capture the first sequence of optional non-digits + one digit to Group 1, then overwrite that Group 1 at least five times... Not optimal.